# How to store Custom logs in Azure Localstorage created using diagnostics.wadcfg

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, enterprise-library

I am using  RollingFlatFileTraceListener(enterprise library v 5) to create Log file which is by default created in my solution.
Also i have created a custom storage in diagnostics.wadcfg

```
<DataSources>
  <DirectoryConfiguration container="wad-abhinandan-custom" directoryQuotaInMB="128">
   <LocalResource name="CustomLogsAzure" relativePath="." />
   </DirectoryConfiguration>
</DataSources>
```

How to i save my log file to CustomLogsAzure so that diagnostic monitor can automatically upload that to Blob storage

Comment: Go the solution here : http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/applisec/archive/2011/05/11/using-logging-application-block-in-azure.aspx
But the Code written at end of post is not complete. Kindly help me out in completing the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way, all depends what you need. You can store files locally on your site or using Diagnostics.

Check

- For Entreprise Library : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2010/09/06/get-logging-in-windows-azure-with-enterprise-library.aspx?Redirected=true
- For NLog : http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.fr/2012/03/getting-nlog-working-with-azure-is-as.html